# How to Integrate Roles Field from "Account Contact Relationship" to Contacts Object Fieldset

Tags: salesforce, contacts, account, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have a field called Role under fields in "Account Contact Relationship". I wanted to integrate this field in contacts Object fieldset. Since am new to salesforce, I don't have any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

Fieldset can contain fields from "this" record and anything that would be "up" relation (via lookup / foreign key if you will). "Up" is for example Contact -> Account, Account -> Owner or Opportunity Line Item -> Opportunity.

But your situation is "down". Contact can have 0, 1 or multiple roles. SF calls these "related lists". How would you imagine fieldset to work if there are 3 roles assigned? And for added complexity what if I'm CEO of Example Ltd but also Head Accountant in SomeCorp Inc?

Maybe edit your question a bit to tell us more what you're trying to achieve. Maybe there's better solution than fieldsets. Maybe if you need to somehow "flatten" roles into a text field (multipicklist?) you'd need to write some code. Fieldsets are more commonly used in Visualforce anyway (no out of the box support in LWC) so not sure why you picked these tags.